When creating a non system user with `adduser`, how do I not add this user to the extra groups?
I am on Ubuntu 24.04 with adduser version 3.137ubuntu1 and I want to add a user like this:
adduser     --comment "john.doe@example.com"     --uid 1010     --home /home/john.doe-example-com     --shell /bin/bash     --disabled-password     john-doe-example-com

By default I get this output:
info: Adding user `john-doe-example-com' ...
info: Adding new group `john-doe-example-com' (1010) ...
info: Adding new user `john-doe-example-com' (1010) with group `john-doe-example-com (1010)' ...
info: Creating home directory `/home/john.doe-example-com' ...
info: Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
info: Adding new user `john-doe-example-com' to supplemental / extra groups `users' ...
info: Adding user `john-doe-example-com' to group `users' ...

The last two lines of the output is what I want to prevent - I do not want to add my new user to the supplemental / extra groups, which are (is) "users" by default.
This default is defined in /etc/adduser.conf:
# list of groups that new non-system users will be added to
# if ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS is non-zero or set on the command line.
# Default: EXTRA_GROUPS="users"
#EXTRA_GROUPS="users"

There is also a setting to disable this, which supposedly is disabled by default:
# Setting this to something other than 0 will cause adduser to add
# newly created non-system users to the list of groups defined by
# EXTRA_GROUPS.
# Default: ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=0
#ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=0

However the user is still added to the group "users".
When I set the following settings in adduser.conf:
EXTRA_GROUPS=""
ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=0

The behavior does not change and it still adds my new user to the "users" group.
I found that if I set this:
# Defines the groupname or GID of the group all newly-created
# non-system users are placed into.
# It is a configuration error to define both variables
# even if the values are consistent.
# Default: USERS_GID=undefined, USERS_GROUP=users
#USERS_GID=100
USERS_GROUP=""

Then it "works" (just not well) - I just get the following warning (see last line of the output)
adduser     --comment "john.doe@example.com"     --uid 1010     --home /home/john.doe-example-com     --shell /bin/bash     --disabled-password     john-doe-example-com 
info: Adding user `john-doe-example-com' ...
info: Adding new group `john-doe-example-com' (1010) ...
info: Adding new user `john-doe-example-com' (1010) with group `john-doe-example-com (1010)' ...
info: Creating home directory `/home/john.doe-example-com' ...
info: Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
info: Adding new user `john-doe-example-com' to supplemental / extra groups `' ...
warn: The group `' does not exist.

So I went to look at the perl code in /usr/sbin/adduser, starting from line 885 I added some debug output:
    if ( ( $add_extra_groups || $config{"add_extra_groups"} ) && defined($config{"extra_groups"}) ) {
        log_info( "ASDFDSAFSAFDSAFDS" );
        log_debug( "add extra_groups from config (%s) to supplemental_groups", $config{"extra_groups"} );
        push (@supplemental_groups, split(/\s+/,$config{"extra_groups"}));
    }
    if ( @supplemental_groups ) {

        log_info( "foobar (%s)", $config{"add_extra_groups"} );
        log_info( "foobar222 (%s)", @supplemental_groups );

Which gives me this output:
info: foobar (0)
info: foobar222 (users)

Meaning that add_extra_groups is 0 (false in perl) and supplemental_groups is "users". This is strange, as I explicitly disabled this in /etc/adduser.conf.
I don't quite get why, but I didn't read the whole perl script ;)
Whats the right way to add a user with adduser and not add it to those extra groups?
I tried disabling to add new users to the extra groups in /etc/adduser.conf

The man page says "If you don't want all your users to be in one group, set USERGROUPS=yes, leave USERS_GROUP empty and set USERS_GID to "-1"." - perhaps it's the last piece ("set USERS_GID to "-1".") that you are missing?

this makes adduser abort with this error:
warn: USERS_GID and USERS_GROUP both given in configuration. This is an error.


The solution:
The only change in /etc/adduser.conf that is required in order to not add new Linux users to the users group, or to the groups defined in USERS_GROUP in /etc/adduser.conf by default is:
USERS_GID=-1

Thank you @steeldriver for pointing in the right direction!
